# How to resolve Property subscribe does not exist on type 'number' error in Ionic Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

The below code is used in an Ionic 5 / Angular tutorial to update a `Place` object. I am trying to apply this same code to my project where I update a `Conversation` object:

*Place Service:*

```
private _places = new BehaviorSubject<Place[]>([
    new Place(
      'p1',
      'Manhattan Mansion',
      'In the heart of New York City.',
      'https://lonelyplanetimages.imgix.net/mastheads/GettyImages-538096543_medium.jpg?sharp=10&vib=20&w=1200',
      149.99,
      new Date('2019-01-01'),
      new Date('2019-12-31'),
      'abc'
    )
  ]);

  get places() {
    return this._places.asObservable();
  }

updatePlace(placeId: string, title: string, description: string) {
    return this.places.pipe(
      take(1),
      delay(1000),
      tap(places => {
        const updatedPlaceIndex = places.findIndex(pl => pl.id === placeId);
        const updatedPlaces = [...places];
        const oldPlace = updatedPlaces[updatedPlaceIndex];
        updatedPlaces[updatedPlaceIndex] = new Place(
          oldPlace.id,
          title,
          description,
          oldPlace.imageUrl,
          oldPlace.price,
          oldPlace.availableFrom,
          oldPlace.availableTo,
          oldPlace.userId
        );
        this._places.next(updatedPlaces);
      })
    );
  }
```

And here is the `Place` model:

```
export class Place {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public title: string,
    public description: string,
    public imageUrl: string,
    public price: number,
    public availableFrom: Date,
    public availableTo: Date,
    public userId: string
  ) {}
}
```

As you can see, the above `updatePlace()` method can be subscribed to when called.

I am trying to create an `addMessageToConversation()` method that can also be subscribed to, exactly like above.

Here is my code so far:

*Conversation Service:*

```
private _conversations = new BehaviorSubject<Conversation[]>([
    new Conversation(
      'conversation1',
      'user3',
      'user1',
      [
        new Message('message1', 'Test message', 'user3', new Date(2018, 0O5, 0O5, 17, 23, 42, 11)),
        new Message('message2', 'Another message', 'user1', new Date(2018, 0O6, 0O5, 17, 23, 42, 11))
      ])
  ]);

  get conversations() {
    return this._conversations.asObservable();
  }

addMessageToConversation(conversationId: string, message: string) {
    this._conversations.getValue().find(conversation => conversation.id === conversationId)
      .messages.push(
        new Message(
          Math.random().toString(),
          message,
          this.authService.userId,
          new Date(Date.now())
        ));
  }
```

And here are the `Conversation` & `Message` models:

```
export class Conversation {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public userId: string,
        public mechanicId: string,
        public messages: Message[]
    ) { }
}

export class Message {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public text: string,
        public userId: string,
        public timestamp: Date
    ) { }
}
```

The above code does update `conversations`, but I can't subscribe to the method. Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make so that this is possible?

If I `return` what is in `addMessageToConversation()` & try to `subscribe` to it, I get this error message:

> Property `subscribe` does not exist on type 'number'

Also, if I try to remove the `_` from `this._conversations.getValue().find(conversation => ...`, then I get this error message:

> Property 'getValue' does not exist on type
>   'Observable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the conversations array from the `BehaviorSubject` out-of-the-box, because it always re-emits the last value to new subscribers. Then the rest is simple.

```js
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {empty} from 'rxjs';

// Obs: notice we're returning a void observable (the empty() at the end),
//    to avoid returning an out-of-date value for the modified conversation.

addMessageToConversation(
  conversationId: string, 
  message: string
): Observable<Conversation> {
  return this._conversations.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((conversations) => conversations.find(c => c.id === conversationId)),
      tap((c: Conversation) => {
        // return case c or messages is falsey
        if(!c?.messages) {return;}

        c.messages.push(
          new Message(
            Math.random().toString(),
            message,
            this.authService.userId,
            new Date(Date.now())
          ));

        // Re-emit conversations array (with new reference)
        this._conversations.next(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this._conversations])));
      }),

      // This step is optional, just to avoid returning an out-of-date conversation
      switchMap((_oldConversation: Conversation) => empty())
  );
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```js
addMessageToConversation('conversation1', 'Hey, look! A new message')
  .subscribe();
```